# Wordpress - Не отображается плагин при создании/редактировании кастомного типа записи

Tags: wordpress

У меня установлен плагин для мультиязычности (локализации). Он позволяет заполнять данные поста на выбранных языках. Отображается он при создании/редактировании категорий, записей, страниц. Но я создал кастомный тип записей и в нем данный плагин не отображается. Покопался в настройках - ничего, из-за чего бы он мог так вести себя - нет. Ну и в обычных типах записей и постов отображается нормально. Может кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой, буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Какой плагин используется для мультиязычности?

Comment: Плагин multilanguage от разработчиков bestwebsoft хотел использовать. Но поскольку в бесплатной версии этого плагина локализация доступна только для стандартных типов записей, то использую QTranslate X

Comment: В вопросе укажите название плагина

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Бесплатную версию плагина Multilanguage by BestWebSoft можно использовать только для стандартных типов записей, для произвольных - надо покупать.

Answer (score 0):

Точно сказать не могу, т.к. Вы не указали даже названия плагина.

Но, вероятнее всего этот плагин не рассчитан на использование с кастомными типами записей. Здесь либо дорабатывать этот плагин под себя (если такая возможность есть), либо одно из двух. Искать другой плагин и писать новый самому.

Comment: Плагин multilanguage от разработчиков bestwebsoft. Но похоже я понял в чем проблема: бесплатную версию этого плагина можно использовать только для стандартных типов записей

Comment: Что и требовалось доказать. Тут уже от Вас зависит. Либо покупаете платную версию либо ищите/пишете что-то другое.